# Bean scanned into Dispatcher servlet cannot find a file

Tags: spring, servlets

I have a utility.jar that comprises of a bunch of Spring beans under /src/main/java and a startup.json under src/main/resources.

The beans are scanned into a seperate org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet context.  Now although the startup.json file is packaged correctly in the JAR, at runtime, I am getting the following exception

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/webapps/xxx/WEB-INF/lib/utility-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/startup.json (No such file or directory)
```

The code that I am using to read the JSON file is

```
  Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("startup.json");
  try {
    fileReader = new FileReader(resource.getURL().getFile());
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    logger.error("File not found to create file reader {} ", e);
    return Collections.emptySet();
  }
```

The dispatcher servlet itself is the child context of the root application context of a web application WAR file. Isn't the JAR on the classpath at runtime in case of the web application?

Comment: A resource inside a jar file inside a war file is NOT a file. A file lives on the file system. Not inside a jar file inside a war file. Don't use getURL().getFile(). Don't use a FileReader to read it. Just use getInputStream(): https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html#getInputStream--, and read from that InputStream.

Comment: Thanks. That worked